# How to encapsulate local Maven/Eclipse project dependency as a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have some Eclipse/Maven projects with complex dependencies. To simplify just consider projects `A`, `B`, and `C` where `A` and `B` are independent but both have a dependency on a common project C. Project C contains a bunch of service interface definitions that don't change very often.

Now I want to split up projects A and B into their own separate repositories, with separate build pipelines, etc. Project C is very simple and may not even have its own CI pipeline.

And here's the rub, I need things to work smoothly whether a developer has one, two, or all three projects checked out simultaneously, without any developer having to take extra configuration steps. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since both A and B require project C the jar of C project just needs to be provided.

A clean approach would be to add the C jar dependency in a nexus repository.

Adding the C jar dependency to A and B from your nexus repository would fetch the jar.

If a nexus repository is not an option you can include the C jar in projects A and B together with a script to install it in the local maven repo. (Or another way to use the jar smoothly)  However everytime C is updated A and B will need to be updated. 
So in practice when C is checked out A and B should be checked out too.